# Add a svg icon before a link in menu YML

Tags: 8, navigation

I've created a link menu and I want to add a SVG icon before it.

This is my YML :

```
double_vue_klesia.listeSwitch2:
  title: 'Double vue Klesia'
  route_name: double_vue_klesia.listeSwitch
  menu_name: navigation-principale
  weight: 4
  options:
    attributes:
      class:
        - listeSwitchMenuItem
```

I though adding a class and in CSS, adding the svg content would do the trick, but clearly it doesn't because it's breaking menu CSS.

This is my css :

```
.listeSwitchMenuItem::before{
  content: url(../images/active.svg);
}
```

Is there another way more clean to do this through YML directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this is for the top level of the admin toolbar...

If you want to follow core strictly you could convert your image file to an inline data: image string, but the benefits are negligible.

The icon is purely CSS, not configured, so nothing in the YML can help to control it.

You could, probably, theoretically, add a "style" attribute and put it inline, but you're in the realms of bad practice at that point.

Comment: No, this is for my main navigation (not for the toolbar ^^). I want to avoid bad practice, I believe the solution I tried is bad practice

Comment: I'd disagree, that seems like the best way to solve that problem. Unless you can do away with setting the attribute altogether in YML, and just target the item in a more natural CSS-selector-y way

Answer (score 0):

agree with @Clive on comment, but do you want(not before):

> class: not needed

```
  attributes:
    class:
      - listeSwitchMenuItem
    style:
      - "background:url('url-image.svg') no-repeat 0px 0px;background-size:3px 3px"
```

Comment: I would like something like this